# iphone: In group section tableview how do you disable section in search result?

Tags: iphone, ios, indexing, tableview

I am using searchDisplayController and it would be searching for the names and also the sections. i would like to know how to show the results of only names and not including the section. Assume the codes are the similar as from apples doc. I have at least 2000 names in there when viewing the tableview itself.

[image]

Comment: you can every time ask is you using searchDisplayTableView or self.tableview when u send numbers of sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to this question:

[UISearchBar Search table row with text, subtext and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303070/uisearchbar-search-table-row-with-text-subtext-and-image/8191803#8191803)

What you show in a results table is completely up to you. It needn't even have anything to do with the table you're searching! (But of course it usually does, as otherwise you'd confuse the user.) You simply form the data that populates the results table; what data that is, is your call.

So, if you don't want to include any section titles, then when the table inquiring of your data source / delegate is the results table, don't include any section titles! It's your code, it's your table, do whatever you want. You are the one implementing `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` to return titles; if you don't want titles, return nil instead. Of course, if the data source for the real table is the same object as the data source for the results table, then `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` will have to examine the incoming `tableView` parameter to see whether it is the real table or the results table, and make its choice of what to return based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to a bit more of your problem as it is not much clear. I don't actually get this line:

> i would like to know how to show the results of only names and not including the section

For searching, it is best to search in a dictionary/array and show the result in tableview by `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: it shows the headers section I have also posted up the screen shot of the search result.

Comment: Perhaps I got the idea. You may try this thing : Create a BOOL flag as 'nameSearchedFlag'. Set this flag in Searchbar textDidChange method. Here you also reload the tableView.
In numberOfSectionsInTableView, check for this flag. If YES, then return 1, else return what you normally return. Then you will get only one section and all the search result names in that section.