# UISearchBar displays no results while typing in text

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my user searches an item in my UISearchBar, results are displayed if the full word typed into the bar matches one of the results. **E.g.** if "Panda" is typed in, Panda pops up in the tableView results. However if "Pan" is typed in, no results are shown. How can I make my search results filter work as the user is typing? Panda should be displayed even if just "pan" is typed in.

My filter code currently looks like this:

**.m**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

/*
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
} */


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else { 

    return [self.neighbourData count];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *NetworkTableIdentifier = @"sidebarCell";

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)

    {



        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"sidebarCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {



        NSDictionary *userName = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"first name"]];

        NSDictionary *userlast = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell lastName] setText:[userlast objectForKey:@"last name"]];

        NSDictionary *userBio = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"userbio"]];



        NSString *profilePath = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo_path"];

        [cell.usermini sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

        NSLog(@"This is profilePath %@",profilePath);



    } else {

    NSDictionary *userName = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"first name"]];

    NSDictionary *userlast = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell lastName] setText:[userlast objectForKey:@"last name"]];

    NSDictionary *userBio = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"userbio"]];



    NSString *profilePath = [[self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo_path"];

    [cell.usermini sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

    NSLog(@"This is profilePath %@",profilePath);




    }
    return cell;

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 115;
}
```

**neighbourData Log:**

```
[12663:3559832] This is the neighbourdata (
        {
        address = "1144 fake street";
        city = Las Vegas;
        "first name" = Panda;
        "last name" = Zoo;
        "photo_path" = "none";
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {
       NSPredicate * predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@",@"first name", searchText];
       searchResults = [self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
     if searchResults.count == 0
     {
        NSPredicate * predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@",@"last name",searchText];
        searchResults = [self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
     }
// add predicates for other keys also if you want

        [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Suggestions:

- Avoid spaces between words of keys ('first name' this is not recommended, 'firstName' recommended)
- And save values in all lowercase ('Panda', 'Zoo' its better to save as 'panda','zoo' this will make search more simpler)

Comment: This causes the following SIGABRT error the moment I start typing inside the search bar : 'Unable to parse the format string "first name contains[cd] %@"'

Comment: The space is definitely what's causing the crash - is there a way to search that field without removing the space? At this stage, it's too late for me to change the field name :/ lol help!

Comment: This works (for the most part) - however if I start typing in the last name after the first name, it clears my results? I suppose it only filters the first name OR the last name, and not both together?

Comment: as you are saving name in two separate fields, its bit difficult to handle the mentioned situation.

Comment: Figured as much - thanks so much for your help! Your rock :)

Answer (score 0):

The method "filterContentForSearchText" should be in "textDidChange" method of UISearchBar. Where are you writing this method currently?

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

---

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.neighbourData = @[@"Apple", @"App", @"Bell"];


    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"filterCell"];


}



    - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                        predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                        searchText];

        self.searchResults = [self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    }

    /*
     -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
     shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
     {
     [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
     scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
     objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

     return YES;
     } */


    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {


        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            return [self.searchResults count];

        } else {

            return [self.neighbourData count];

        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell  * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filterCell"];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"filterCell"];
        }



        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

            cell.textLabel. text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        } else {

            cell.textLabel. text = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }

        return cell;

@end
```

Comment: See code edit. If this is the case, what should my BOOL be changed to? As changing the line you suggested causes the BOOL to throw me an error.

Comment: Okay.You're using UISearchDisplayController(It's deprecated in ios8. alternative is UISearchController). Try comment out this code. I would recommend to use UISearchController if your app doesn't support < ios8.

Comment: I commented out the BOOL. Even with the above line of code in place, it's still not filtering as I type inside the search bar :/ See edits again - pasted my full search code in.

Comment: Added a code. Table view is getting reloaded automatically. We don't need to call explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your tableview after your data filtered and also remove exist object for searchResult array.

```
   - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {
      NSPredicate * predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first name = %@", searchText];
     searchResults = [self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
     [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: [searchResults removeAllObjects];  Adding this line throws me the error "No visible interface for NSArray declares the selector removeAllObjects".

Comment: ok then remove that line because your array type is NSArray instead of NSMutableArray .

Comment: Removed that line - search bar still doesn't filter as I'm typing text.

Comment: have you got any result on searchResults ?

Comment: Yes - I get a result when the full word is typed. E.g. if I type "Panda", Panda is returned. However if I type "Pa", nothing is returned.

Comment: give me log of neighbourData .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130454/discussion-between-kkrocks-and-brittany).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this predicate block:

```
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
                  ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *d) {
                      NSString* s = obj;
                      NSStringCompareOptions options = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch;
                      return ([s rangeOfString:sbc.searchBar.text 
                                       options:options].location != NSNotFound);
                  }];
self.filteredStates = [states filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Meanwhile checkout this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303070/uisearchbar-search-table-row-with-text-subtext-and-image).

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is "sbc"?? Undeclared?

Comment: Use searchText  instead of sbc.searchBar.text